# My Garmin Zumo 590 does not show up in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, gps

I am really new to Linux and Ubuntu. I have two Garmin GPS - one is a Nuvi 750 and the other is a Zumo 590. The Nuvi 750 shows up in Files when it is plugged into a USB port, but the Zumo 590 does not. Since the Zumo 590 does not show up as a USB device when plugged in, is there something I can do to figure out what the most likely problem and how to solve it?